# Fetch date of unexpected system shutdown from EventData

Tags: event-log, readeventlog

Windows' Event ID `6008` is `Unexpected Shutdown` event (see in System's [Event Viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer)). The problem is that time of the unexpected system's shutdown is written in [bytes array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry.data.aspx) (which is called `EventData`).

I want to fetch this date (in my *C#* application) from `EventData` but I don't know how time is encoded in bytes array.

Comment: Why can't you use the [TimeGenerated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry.timegenerated.aspx) property

Comment: Because `TimeGenerated`>=`Time of the unexpected shutdown`. It's not the same.